# H-alpha velocity fields of spirals falling into a cluster

Tags: galaxy, spectroscopy, galaxy-cluster, h-alpha

What kind of impact would you expect ram pressure stripping / tidal interactions / harassment / interactions with the cluster potential (etc!) to have on the h-alpha velocity fields of infalling spiral galaxies? 
What I mean is, how easy is it to detect such processes at work, and how are you able to distinguish between these different mechanisms (using also h-alpha intensity maps, rotation curves, optical morphologies if available).

Cheers!

Comment: Possibly relevant paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.01883